# Insert line break on same position as in another string

Tags: python, string

I have two strings:

```
s1 = '''One scientist
        said'''  

s2 = 'One man said'
```

I need to put '\n' sign instead space in s2 after second word as in s1.
Lika that:

```
s2 = '''One man 
        said'''
```

But how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
s2 = 'One man said'
x = s2.split()[:2] # First two words
y = s2.split()[2:] # After first two
text_to_add = '\n        ' # Change if you want
out = x + text_to_add + y
print(out)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution, it's really simple:

```py
s2 = 'One man\n said'
```

Comment: You didn't understand my question...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).